# HTML submit form and PHP doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I am completely new to PHP/MySQL. I basicaly have a html form and I want to use PHP to send all the values to a database. For some reason when I click on submit I only go to a new page where it shows all my PHP code in the browser window. Is this normal? And how can I fix it?
Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="display.php">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Username..."/>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email address..."/>
        <input name="date" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"/>
        <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
        <input name="confirm_password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["password"] != $_REQUEST["confirm_password"]){
}else {
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];

$dns = 'mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost';
$db = new PDO($dsn, '', '');

$stmt=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbUsers(username,email) VALUES ($name,$email)');  
$stmt->execute(array($myvalue));

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you executing the scripts on localhost? Have you set up your web server and PHP correctly?

Comment: Go to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html and install Xampp on your system.

Comment: You need to install a server in order for the PHP code to be executed. I recommend you to use WAMP server http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: +1 for being new to PHP but knowing to use PDO library instead of the old mysql_xxx functions. Too many people reading out of date tutorials; it's good to see someone getting at least this basic detail right. :-)

Comment: Seems to be a server configuration error. I could better help you if you provide a server type (linux? windows?) and the software you're using (apache? PHP5?)

Comment: I installed WAMP first and then I used XAMPP, but still the sam thing happens. Can it be because PHP isn't installed because I thought PHP is installed with the XAMPP/WAMP packages

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a web server configured properly, the PHP would not be executed the way it should be.

Ensure that you have a localhost configured correctly before trying to execute your web app.

If you need a localhost, you could try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for your local machine. If you are going to be using another host, ensure that they have PHP installed on the server.

If you do not want to use a prepackaged server such as the ones above, you can install PHP on your own by following the installation steps on the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php).

Answer (score 0):

No, thats probably not normal :)

You probably haven't configured your server to use PHP

First make sure PHP is installed on the server

Then take a look here for how to configure your particular server
http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

If you are using a linux based system, your package manager (ie, apt) will usually call the appropriate triggers when you install PHP such that it is automatically integrated into your system.

If you want a full LAMP (linux apache mysql php) stack you can do `sudo apt-get install tasksel; sudo tasksel` and check off 'LAMP Server'.  This will guide you through all the setup and configuration